# Cannot save changes made in gnome-settings

Tags: linux, fedora, gnome

I have a fresh install of fedora 24. I have some issues with not being able to change anything in Gnome. Ex: I go to All Settings -> Power and want to set the time to go to blank screen to: Never. What happens is, well, nothing. This goes for every change I try to make.

Another issue that might be related is that after the first reboot I can no longer start gnome-terminal. When I do I get this error:

```
Error constructing proxy for org.gnome.Terminal:/org/gnome/Terminal/Factory0: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gnome.Terminal: Timeout was reached
```

I don't know where to start here. I have never had this problem before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, so after I tried some more things I got another error:

```
dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: 
DBus.Error:org.gtk.GDBus.UnmappedGError.Quark._g_2dfile_2derror_2dquark.Code17:
Cannot open dconf database: invalid gvdb header
```

So I figured that meant something was wrong with ~/.config/dconf 
The solution was that I just deleted ~/.config/dconf now everything works fine.